# Why is this SQL query returning this result?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone tell me why this sql query is returning this result.

```
SELECT
      M.MatterNumber_Id, M.MatterNumber, M.MatterName, 
      ISNULL(MP.Role_Cd, 'No Primary') AS PrimaryRole, 
      ISNULL(E.Name, 'No Primary') AS PrimaryName, 
      ISNULL(C.CommNumber, 'l.w@abc.ca;m.j@abc.com') AS Email

FROM
     Matter M 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     MatterPlayer MP ON M.MatterNumber_Id = MP.MatterNumber_Id AND  
     MP.Role_Cd IN ('Primary Lawyer', 'Primary Staff Member') AND
     MP.EndDate IS NULL 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Entity E on MP.Entity_EID = E.Entity_EID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Communication C on MP.Entity_EID = C.Entity_EID AND 
     C.CommunicationType_Cd = 'Email' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     MatterExposure ME on M.MatterNumber_Id = ME.MatterNumber_Id AND  
     ME.AssessedDate > '7/10/2014' AND 
     ME.Currency_CD IS NOT NULL

WHERE 
    M.MatterStatus_Cd = 'Active' AND 
    ME.AssessedDate IS NULL AND
    M.Matter_Cd in 
                  (SELECT 
                         rpl.Type_CD 
                   FROM 
                         RuleProfile_Tabs rpt   
                   INNER JOIN 
                         RuleProfile_LookupCode rpl ON rpt.RuleProfile_ID = rpl.RuleProfile_ID   
                   WHERE 
                         tab_id = 1034 AND Caption LIKE 'Reportable Matter%')                   
ORDER BY 
    Email, M.MatterName
```

But When i see the results I check one of the records returned and it should not have been returned.

One of the results returned:
Bailey, Richard

In the db i check the values in the tables it should not have been returned because Currency_CD is null and in the sql it states currency_cd is not null.  Also the assessed date is AFTER 7/10/2014

Table Values:

```
MatterStatus_CD:
Active           
AssessedDate:
7/24/2014
Currency_CD:
NULL
EndDate:
NULL
```

Comment: The `Currency_CD IS NOT NULL` condition is in an `on` clause for a `left join`.  Hence, it is not acting as a filter they way you want it, it is acting as a join condition.

Comment: `ME.Currency_CD IS NOT NULL` the IS NOT NULL part should be move to the where clause

Answer (score 0):

Where clauses are used for filtering, not the join clause. Every JOIN should have an ON. Here's a head start.

```
Select M.MatterNumber_Id, M.MatterNumber, M.MatterName, 
IsNull(MP.Role_Cd, 'No Primary') as PrimaryRole, 
IsNull(E.Name, 'No Primary') as PrimaryName, 
IsNull(C.CommNumber, 'l.w@abc.ca;m.j@abc.com') as Email

From Matter M 
Left Outer Join MatterPlayer MP on M.MatterNumber_Id = MP.MatterNumber_Id   
Left Outer Join Entity E on MP.Entity_EID = E.Entity_EID 
Left Outer Join Communication C on MP.Entity_EID = C.Entity_EID   
Left Outer Join MatterExposure ME on M.MatterNumber_Id = ME.MatterNumber_Id   


Where M.MatterStatus_Cd = 'Active' 
AND ME.AssessedDate is Null 
and M.Matter_Cd in (select  rpl.Type_CD 
                    from RuleProfile_Tabs rpt   
                        inner join RuleProfile_LookupCode rpl on rpt.RuleProfile_ID = rpl.RuleProfile_ID   
                    where tab_id = 1034 AND Caption like 'Reportable Matter%')                  
and MP.Role_Cd In ('Primary Lawyer', 'Primary Staff Member')   
and MP.EndDate is Null 
and ME.AssessedDate > '7/10/2014' 
and ME.Currency_CD IS NOT NULL
and C.CommunicationType_Cd = 'Email' 

Order by Email, M.MatterName
```

Comment: When I do it this way, there are no results that are returned now.

Comment: put mock data into a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) and i'll mess with it more

Answer (score 0):

You are LEFT JOINing `MatterExposure` onto `Matter`. Your `Me.Currency_CD IS NOT NULL` criteria in the LEFT JOIN's ON statement is only saying, "don't join to records where Currency_CD is null..." but because this is a left join, none of your `Matter` table's records are lost in the join. So when you ask for `Currency_CD` you will get `NULL`.

To remove records from your query where `Currency_CD` is null in the `MatterExposure` table you will either need to specify `Currency_CD IS NOT NULL` in your where statement (instead of your join) or will need to  use an INNER JOIN to your `MatterExposure` table.

Answer (score 0):

It is because this join is a LEFT OUTER JOIN. If you want to enforce this join make it an inner join. Or move that check to the WHERE clause.